# Running virtualbox in parallels with windows

Tags: virtualbox, parallels, arm

Is there a way to run virtualbox within parallels using windows on an m2 Mac?

I"m working on a pokerbot ([www.github.com/dickreuter/Poker](http://www.github.com/dickreuter/Poker)) that plays poker online automatically by scraping the client. The pokerclient needs to be in a virtual machine to run.

On my mac, I'd like to test if the code runs correctly in windows. For that I run windows in parallel. But inside parallel I need another virtual windows (or mac environment).

Comment: What do you mean? You want to run a Type-2 hypervisor (VBox) within a Type-2 hypervisor (Parallels) to run a Virtual Machine, host OS being Windows running on M2 Mac???

Comment: That might be a question for Parallels support… but *why*? Are you hoping to be able to run X86 inside ARM in some way? Wouldn't it be better to ask about what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than about how you think you will achieve it?  That's what we call an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: VirtualBox does not support *Windows 11 on ARM* at this time. I don’t believe you can even enable nested virtualization on ARM hardware. Recall that Apple silicon at its core is ARM based

Comment: You are asking why. Because I'm working on a pokerbot that I need to support for windows users as well. The pokerbot (www.github.com/dickreuter/Poker) needs to have the poker client run in a VM. In order to simulate this on my m2, I need nested virtualization.

Comment: First, I recommend reading the Help section to learn how this site works. Second edit your question to make it more clear rather than adding info in comments. Don't think of comments as a conversation, if that helps. Third, you're just saying you want this because you only have a m2 Mac and want to run Windows on it?

Comment: added additional explanations, how this helps to better understand the context